# How to Ignore specific fields from a JSON string while deserialising in c#?

Tags: c#, json

I am having a JSON response String that is a complex class, it looks like under mentioned :-

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "_id": "5d4d767270de4b0008c3cb10",
        "CH_SYMBOL": "TITAN",
        "CH_SERIES": "EQ",
        "CH_MARKET_TYPE": "N",
        "CH_TRADE_HIGH_PRICE": 250.3,
        "CH_TRADE_LOW_PRICE": 246,
        "CH_OPENING_PRICE": 247.6,
        "CH_CLOSING_PRICE": 247.55,
        "CH_LAST_TRADED_PRICE": 246.8,
        "CH_PREVIOUS_CLS_PRICE": 246.1,
        "CH_TOT_TRADED_QTY": 1502182,
        "CH_TOT_TRADED_VAL": 372907497.3,
        "CH_52WEEK_HIGH_PRICE": 4754.95,
        "CH_52WEEK_LOW_PRICE": 154.2,
        "CH_TOTAL_TRADES": 25225,
        "CH_ISIN": "INE280A01028",
        "CH_TIMESTAMP": "2012-03-13",
        "TIMESTAMP": "2012-03-12T18:30:00.000Z",
        "createdAt": "2019-08-09T13:34:42.045Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-08-09T13:34:42.045Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "VWAP": 248.24,
        "mTIMESTAMP": "13-Mar-2012"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5d4d76b46c032c0008a78a0a",
        "CH_SYMBOL": "TITAN",
        "CH_SERIES": "EQ",
        "CH_MARKET_TYPE": "N",
        "CH_TRADE_HIGH_PRICE": 247.9,
        "CH_TRADE_LOW_PRICE": 241.2,
        "CH_OPENING_PRICE": 244.3,
        "CH_CLOSING_PRICE": 246.1,
        "CH_LAST_TRADED_PRICE": 246.5,
        "CH_PREVIOUS_CLS_PRICE": 239.95,
        "CH_TOT_TRADED_QTY": 2602734,
        "CH_TOT_TRADED_VAL": 636810839.3,
        "CH_52WEEK_HIGH_PRICE": 4754.95,
        "CH_52WEEK_LOW_PRICE": 154.2,
        "CH_TOTAL_TRADES": 28433,
        "CH_ISIN": "INE280A01028",
        "CH_TIMESTAMP": "2012-03-12",
        "TIMESTAMP": "2012-03-11T18:30:00.000Z",
        "createdAt": "2019-08-09T13:35:48.154Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-08-09T13:35:48.154Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "VWAP": 244.67,
        "mTIMESTAMP": "12-Mar-2012"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5d4d7596d3f11300086653dc",
        "CH_SYMBOL": "TITAN",
        "CH_SERIES": "EQ",
        "CH_MARKET_TYPE": "N",
        "CH_TRADE_HIGH_PRICE": 241.4,
        "CH_TRADE_LOW_PRICE": 231.2,
        "CH_OPENING_PRICE": 234.1,
        "CH_CLOSING_PRICE": 239.95,
        "CH_LAST_TRADED_PRICE": 239.75,
        "CH_PREVIOUS_CLS_PRICE": 231.4,
        "CH_TOT_TRADED_QTY": 3178144,
        "CH_TOT_TRADED_VAL": 755500633.45,
        "CH_52WEEK_HIGH_PRICE": 4754.95,
        "CH_52WEEK_LOW_PRICE": 154.2,
        "CH_TOTAL_TRADES": 41314,
        "CH_ISIN": "INE280A01028",
        "CH_TIMESTAMP": "2012-03-09",
        "TIMESTAMP": "2012-03-08T18:30:00.000Z",
        "createdAt": "2019-08-09T13:31:02.992Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-08-09T13:31:02.992Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "VWAP": 237.72,
        "mTIMESTAMP": "09-Mar-2012"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5d4d76951063e700088d810e",
        "CH_SYMBOL": "TITAN",
        "CH_SERIES": "EQ",
        "CH_MARKET_TYPE": "N",
        "CH_TRADE_HIGH_PRICE": 234.4,
        "CH_TRADE_LOW_PRICE": 227.4,
        "CH_OPENING_PRICE": 229,
        "CH_CLOSING_PRICE": 231.4,
        "CH_LAST_TRADED_PRICE": 231.4,
        "CH_PREVIOUS_CLS_PRICE": 230.8,
        "CH_TOT_TRADED_QTY": 2133389,
        "CH_TOT_TRADED_VAL": 492988507.9,
        "CH_52WEEK_HIGH_PRICE": 4754.95,
        "CH_52WEEK_LOW_PRICE": 154.2,
        "CH_TOTAL_TRADES": 27837,
        "CH_ISIN": "INE280A01028",
        "CH_TIMESTAMP": "2012-03-07",
        "TIMESTAMP": "2012-03-06T18:30:00.000Z",
        "createdAt": "2019-08-09T13:35:17.664Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-08-09T13:35:17.664Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "VWAP": 231.08,
        "mTIMESTAMP": "07-Mar-2012"
    },
],
"meta": {
    "series": [
        "EQ"
    ],
    "fromDate": "13-03-2010",
    "toDate": "13-03-2012",
    "symbols": [
        "TITAN",
        "TITAN"
    ]
}
```

}

Now I made my C# class structure to be like this

```
    public class Data {
 public string _id { get; set; }
 public string CH_SYMBOL { get; set; }
 public string CH_SERIES { get; set; }
 public string CH_MARKET_TYPE { get; set; }
 public double CH_TRADE_HIGH_PRICE { get; set; }
 public int CH_TRADE_LOW_PRICE { get; set; }
 public double CH_OPENING_PRICE { get; set; }
 public double CH_CLOSING_PRICE { get; set; }
 public double CH_LAST_TRADED_PRICE { get; set; }
 public double CH_PREVIOUS_CLS_PRICE { get; set; }
 public int CH_TOT_TRADED_QTY { get; set; }
 public double CH_TOT_TRADED_VAL { get; set; }
 public double CH_52WEEK_HIGH_PRICE { get; set; }
 public double CH_52WEEK_LOW_PRICE { get; set; }
 public int CH_TOTAL_TRADES { get; set; }
 public string CH_ISIN { get; set; }
 public string CH_TIMESTAMP { get; set; }
 public DateTime TIMESTAMP { get; set; }
 public DateTime createdAt { get; set; }
 public DateTime updatedAt { get; set; }
 public int __v { get; set; }
 public double VWAP { get; set; }
 public DateTime mTIMESTAMP { get; set; }

}
public class Meta {
 public IList<string> series { get; set; }
 public string fromDate { get; set; }
 public string toDate { get; set; }
 public IList<string> symbols { get; set; }

}
public class Application {
 public IList<Data> data { get; set; }
public Meta meta { get; set; } 
}
}
```

Now is it possible to just extract the `public IList<Data> data { get; set; }` and save it.
Instead of creating one instance to class Application, Just `List <Data>` could be extracted from the JSON string.

I am using `JsonConvert.DeserialiseObejct();` to do that, any help would be of great help.
Thanks 
Piyush Kumar

Comment: By default, Json deserialization ignores unknown properties in the target class or model. Have you tried deserializing the data into model?

Comment: I did that, it fails instantly

Comment: For deserializing the Json string to object, it is better to create the complete representation (_c# class or model_). Otherwise, you will end up creating a workaround that will affect the performance eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took some time to figure out, Here the Model contains all the fields from JSON string and `ActualModel` is a class that I need.

```
                        model Model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<model>(whole_table_data_in_JSON, settings);
                        JObject partial = JObject.Parse(whole_table_data_in_JSON);
                        IList<JToken> results = partial["data"].Children().ToList();
                        IList<ActualModel> his = new List<ActualModel>();
                        foreach (JToken result in results)
                        {
                            // JToken.ToObject is a helper method that uses JsonSerializer internally
                            ActualModel temp = result.ToObject<ActualModel>();
                            his.Add(temp);
                        }
```